# como invocar varias veces un reporte en un solo pdf con reportviewer c#

Tags: c#

Quiero mostrar varias veces el mismo reporte pdf en un solo pdf con `reportviewer`.

```
this.ReportDataSets = new List<ReportDataSource>();

this.ReportDataSets.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSetDetalleRecaudoICA", ListaDeRecaudoICA));
this.ReportDataSets.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSetDetalleRecaudoICA", ListaDeRecaudoICA));
```

agrego dos veces pero al generar el pdf solo genera 1

Comment: Bienvenido te invito a leer [ask] y tambien a que hagas [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Lo que estas agregando es dos veces los mismos datos. Eso no tiene nada que ver con que salgan dos reportes. Que quieres hacer? dos copias del mismo informe en el mismo pdf?

Comment: si quiero hacer dos copias de el mismo pdf